# I want to count how many times system call was called in C

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, linux-kernel, operating-system

I want to count how many times systemcall was called.
I make wrapping function in C that hook "open" system call.
first I do was override open.c with openHooking.c
In that code, I added a code that changes shell variable to the original open.c content.
I thought that I could do it by declare environment variable in shell, and change it in C script.
But I realized it is impossible because child process can't change parent process.
I want to know how many times the system call was called
How can I do it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strace` can do this for you with either `--summary`, `--summary-only`, or doing the accounting yourself by analyzing its output!
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html

there are many flags, but perhaps simply

```sh
strace --follow-forks --summary ./a.out
```